# Web Api using Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

We have implemented the basic authentication, OnAuthorization in user variable we are trying to get the current login user detail. It is working when we are trying with browser, but when we are trying to hit end point using mobile service. We are unable to hit the end points because Custom authorization is implemented on Action level. Please help me.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            WMSEntities db = new WMSEntities();

//Get detail of current login user
            string userID = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
            var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == userID);

            if (user == null)
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            else
            {
                bool ok = false;
                foreach (var item in user.AppRoles)
                {
                    foreach (string ar in accessRoleNames)
                    {
                        if (item.Name == ar)
                            ok = true;
                    }
                }
                db.Dispose();

                if (!ok)
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
```

Comment: Did you try with "Debug --> Attach To Process... " and then select w3wp or iisexpress?

Comment: @T N , i have hit the end point from postman with token in header, but end point return 401 reponse.

Comment: 401 is unauthorized. Please check credentials you're passing using postman.